# Clear DropDownList values on SelectedIndexChanged in Dataset c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't clean the values in *DropDownList* **ddlCountry** when I change the value on *DropDownList* **ddlCO**.

I use the **DataSet**.

The values on *DropDownList* **ddlCountry** are merged.

How to resolve this ?

My code below, thank you in advance for any help,really appreciated.

```
protected void ddlCO_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM ");
    sql += String.Format("  `tbl_1` WHERE Country IN (?); ");

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand cmd =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", ddlCO.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (OdbcDataAdapter sda =
                new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ddlCountry.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlCountry.ClearSelection();
                ddlCountry.Enabled = true; 

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                ddlCountry.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryText";
                ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryValue";
                ddlCountry.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to clear it with `.DataSource = null`

Comment: @EpicKip thank you for help, but the *DropDownList* **ddlCountry** is not empty.

Comment: Is the list still filled or only the text of the last selected item? Because if I set the datasource to null my combobox instantly clears

Comment: @EpicKip I have in combobox merged values

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't work. If its a datasource just set it to null. If its a bunch of items just `comboBox.Items.Clear();`

Comment: @EpicKip Thanks! Working with comboBox.Items.Clear()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear a combobox in multiple ways, if it has a `DataSource` you set its datasource to `null`:

```
myComboBox.DataSource = null;
```

And if its not a datasource you can use the `items` collection in the combobox:

```
myComboBox.Items.Clear();
```